# Choice of Node-Js

Tags: rest, node.js

We have a COTS tool which provides REST services. There are many in-house tools which want to consume these services. As owners of COTS tool, we want few policies to be in place for the in-house tools to access the COTS tools REST services. So we are planning to build a layer which would act as a interface between COTS tool and in-house tools. This layer will be consumer for COTS tool REST services and provider for in-house tools needing COTS tool REST services. So this software would need to be a REST service client and also REST service provider. I am evaluating node-js for this development. Can some one validate whether node-js is a decent choice. I am looking in terms of availability of libraries for REST client and provider development, scalability and stability of the solution as this will be used my many users. I also have a choice of using Python and I need to decide one among these two soon. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

node.js combined with [ExpressJS](https://github.com/visionmedia/express) makes building REST interfaces dead simple, especially with the addition of namespacing in ExpressJS 2.0 (due for release soon).  More about Express's upcoming features and examples of how it's used can be found in DailyJS's recent [Node Roundup article](http://dailyjs.com/2011/03/16/node-roundup/).

As for node's viability as a platform, there are some drawbacks which—on the surface—can make it seem less desirable than others, most notably the lack of multi-core processing support.  This has traditionally been addressed by spawning multiple processes, which in the past was a somewhat manual procedure.  Fortunately, TJ Holowaychuk (the developer of ExpressJS) has released a tool called [cluster](https://github.com/LearnBoost/cluster) which automates multi-process spawning and other process management tasks for you.

Comment: Just as reference to others, Node.JS v0.6.0 introduced Cluster. The ability to fork and utilize multi-core systems - http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.0/api/cluster.html